# How do I convert the value from a time input from a HTML form to a time variable in Python?

Tags: python, html, datetime, time

I have a HTML form that takes the input as a hour format. Very simple:

```
<input type="time" name="due_hour" id="due_hour">
```

Then I try to convert it to a time format using datetime:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time
```

Here are the first 2 lines of code to convert:

```
task_due_hour_raw = request.form['due_hour']
task_due_hour_split = task_due_hour_raw.split(':')
```

If I return f"{task_due_hour_split[0]}:{task_due_hour_split[1]}", it does print an hour with the correct format, such as 10:00... So the data I try to push into a time type variable seems to be valid.

However, whenever I try to convert it at the last line:

```
task_due_hour = time(int(task_due_date_split[0]), int(task_due_hour_split[1]), 0, 0)
```

I get this error message:

```
ValueError: hour must be in 0..23
```

If that can be of any use, it's part of a Flask project. The reason I'm doing this is to convert the data into a time variable so that I can use it in a SQL query to create a new line.

Comment: Are you looking to include a day and time, or just a time?

Comment: @PacketLoss just a time. The database has two different columns. One for date and one for time.

Comment: If you are to combine the date and time later, could you not just store the time `10:00` as a `str`?

Comment: In your call to `time` you have `task_due_date_split` where you shoukd have `task_due_hour_split`

Comment: @PacketLoss That column in the SQL database is a time format, but I suppose I could just store it as a string and convert it in the code when needed.

Comment: @Nick Yeah thanks for that. I changed it and it worked...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why it didn't work for you but I tried and looks like working -

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time

task_due_hour_raw = "21:02" #I have just hard coded the value I recieved as a request parameter
task_due_hour_split = task_due_hour_raw.split(':')

print(task_due_hour_split[0])
print(task_due_hour_split[1])

task_due_hour = time(int(task_due_hour_split[0]), int(
    task_due_hour_split[1]), 0, 0)

print(task_due_hour)
```